# What is ~/. and where should I make?

Tags: linux, xmonad

I'm beginner.

I'm trying to use xmonad and reading [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Xmonad/Config_archive/John_Goerzen's_Configuration).
It is written that "Make a directory called ~/.xmonad".

I have questions.

What is "~/."? Is this a part of the file name?

Where should I make this directory?

Comment: ~ is your home directory. So make it under there. Or you could've just said `mkdir ~/.xmonad` and `cd ~/.xmonad` and seen what happens. Then again, props for not running random commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Unix (and Linux) shells, `~` is the user's home folder (like `$HOME`). You are being directed to create a hidden folder (folders that start with a `.` aren't displayed in `ls` by default) named `.xmonad` in the user's home folder.